# Can't connect to mail servers from Laravel 6 on Homestead

Tags: laravel, homestead, portforwarding, mailtrap

[Update]

I've tried using wamp on windows and still can't connect to smtp.mailtrap.io

---

I have this homestead.yml config for ports

```
keys:
  - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

ports:
  - send: 587
    to: 587
  - send: 2525
    to: 2525
    protocol: tcp

folders:
  - map: C:/code
    to: /home/vagrant/code
```

And this .env config

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxx
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=foo@bar.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

But I always get

```
{"error_code":400,"status":"error","message":"","data":"Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailtrap.io
:stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to smtp.mailtrap.io:587 (Connection timed out)"}
```

I tried `SendGrid` too with ports `587` and `2525` but I always get the same message. I tried to connect to mailtrap from ssh

```
telnet mailtrap.io 587
telnet mailtrap.io 2525
```

Also tried this from SSH

```
sudo ufw allow 25/tcp
sudo ufw allow 2525/tcp
sudo ufw allow 587/tcp
```

But in both cases I don't get any response. I tried to change `MAIL_ENCRYPTION` to `tls` but didn't work too.

While starting vagrant I get only these port forwardings

```
==> homestead: Forwarding ports...
homestead: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
homestead: 443 (guest) => 44300 (host) (adapter 1)
homestead: 3306 (guest) => 33060 (host) (adapter 1)
homestead: 4040 (guest) => 4040 (host) (adapter 1)
homestead: 5432 (guest) => 54320 (host) (adapter 1)
homestead: 8025 (guest) => 8025 (host) (adapter 1)
homestead: 9600 (guest) => 9600 (host) (adapter 1)
homestead: 27017 (guest) => 27017 (host) (adapter 1)
homestead: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
```

How can I connect successfully to mailtrap from Laravel on Homestead?

Answer (score 0):

I tried using VPN then tried `telnet` and it worked find and emails got sent so it wasn't any coding or cache issue it was related to connection and closed services or ports solved by using VPN